# Highchart multiple values for data on 1 series

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, highcharts

I have a stored procedure that returns 3 columns, TYPE, AVERAGE, MAX

And on my highchart

```
   series: [{
        name: 'Average Time',
        data: data.AverageTime
      },
    {
        name: 'Max Time',
        data: data.MaxTime
    }]
```

I want both the Average and Max column to be bound to the type. So Type1 series has data.Type1Ave and data.Type1Max, Type2 series has data.Type2Ave and data.Type2Max

is this possible with highchart? So far ive been working with highcharts where only 1 variable is set with the data of the series. thanks.

Comment: Can you write original `json` to apply for series in highchart? Also you should provide fiddle of which chart you are working with.

Comment: It's not a matter of whether it's possible with Highcharts - it's a matter of processing your data to build the right array for Highcharts. Provide a fiddle and an example of your data output for more help

Comment: got it working with the category in highcharts. Thanks. :)